# Concatenate unique Last Names with first name combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a table which I want to find the unique last names and corresponding first names and output them into a string

| FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | Bloggs |
| Anne | Bloggs |
| Mary | Smith |

I have previously used something like this to concatenate a list of people

```
(Select Stuff(
    (Select', ', Left(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName + ',' ,
        Len(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName + ',')-1)  AS 'data()'
     From Person p
     Where p.PersonID in (Select PersonID From @TempTable)
   For XML Path('')
),1,2,'')) People
```

However, I am after an output something like the following and am stuck.

> Bloggs Joe + Anne, Smith Mary

I would really love to only include the first names if there are more than 1 person with the same last name but that is a minor desire.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Side note: Beware of underqualified conditions like `Where p.PersonID in (Select PersonID From @TempTable)`, especially in subselects If `@TempTable` has an `ID` or `Person_ID` column but no `PersonID`, SQL Server will quite happily interpret this as `Where p.PersonID in (Select p.PersonID From @TempTable)` and no error will occur.  (See my profile for the story behind this warning.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, you can use the `STRING_AGG()` function to build a combined list of `FirstName` values after grouping by `LastName`. Adding a `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` condition will eliminate the single-name case.

```
SELECT
    p.LastName + ', '
       + STRING_AGG(p.FirstName, ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY p.FirstName)
       AS People
FROM Person p
WHERE p.PersonID IN (SELECT t.PersonID FROM @TempTable t)
GROUP BY p.LastName
--HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY p.LastName
```

Results (with some extra test data):

| People |
| --- |
| Bloggs, Anne Joe |
| Smith, Mary |
| Stooge, Curly Larry Moe |

Uncomment the `HAVING` clause to eliminate the "Smith, Mary" result.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RADDzNhY).